# How do I move generated excel sheet to specificly 1st and 2nd position

Tags: c#, excel, vba, excel-addins

I'm working on excel add in project.

I'm generating excel sheets from database tables dynamically.

Now I want to move specific excel sheets at position 1st and 2nd.

I tried like following which is correctly working on Office version 2010

but not working for Office version 2013

what should I do for office 2013?

If active sheet comes "MYFirst" I moved this to 1st position using following code

```
Worksheet hiddenSheet;
hiddenSheet = (Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);                            
hiddenSheet.Move(Type.Missing, Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 3]);
// int count = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count;   // in office version 2010 count comes 4   so (4-3=1)
```

If active sheet comes "MYSecond" I moved this to 1st position using following code

```
 Worksheet hiddenSheet;
 hiddenSheet = (Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
 hiddenSheet.Move(Type.Missing, Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 3]);
 // int count = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count;   // in office version 2010  count comes 5    so (5-3=2)
```

How can I achieve this ? Or how to find which version of Office is currently installed so that directly carried out the count difference and specify position directly

MSDN gives this code to move sheet to last position 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhf0ksb.aspx

```
int totalSheets = this.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count;
((Excel.Worksheet)Application.ActiveSheet).Move(
    this.Application.Worksheets[totalSheets]);
```

How to move sheet to first position ?

Comment: What's the behaviour if you work with new workbooks? I thought Excel 2010 has 3 sheets and 2013 has only got 1 by default. Have you got any `Chart sheets` in there?

Comment: exactly right 2010 has 3 and 2013 has 1 because of that it is unable to move have to change my MOVE SHEET expression. but how? which is the good way todo so ? btw every time i'm working on a new workbook which will create sheets from database

Comment: if you want to move it to the first position then try `hiddenSheet.Move(Before: Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[1]);`

Comment: great what about 2nd position ?

Comment: `hiddenSheet.Move(After: Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[1]);` ??

Comment: is there anything I can do to improve my answer? you have thanked me for helping but never accepted my answer :(

Comment: no acceptance so i think my deleted now answer didnt help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the sheet is already in the excel workbook

Let the sheet be called MyFirstSheet

Let the Excel workbook be called book

To move the sheet MyFirstSheet to the first position in the excel workbook:

```
private static void moveSheetToFirstPosition(Excel.Workbook book){
    book.Sheets["MyFirstSheet"].Move(book.Sheets[1]);
}
```

That will put it in the first position.

If you have 2 sheets to move, FirstSheet, SecondSheet, simply move SecondSheet to Sheet[1], then move FirstSheet Sheets[1]. Thus making the second sheet in position 2.

Hope this helps.